# Pass arguments(a list) from /bin/sh to python

Tags: python, bash, sh

I am having a `test.py` file that are below:

```
year= sys.argv[1]
for i in range(len(year)):
   
    print("Working on year",year[i])
```

`year` should take a list of years such as `['2021','2022']` and loop thru it. And I am constructing a `.sh` file that can just pass a list of years to python.Here is the `test.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

year=$1


echo 'Working on' $year 'year'

python path/test.py $year
```

I am hoping to have it set up correctly so I can just run this in command line:

`sh test.sh '2021 2022'`

and it'd print out years. However, it loop thru `2,0,2,1` instead of `2021` and `2022`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just generate this list of years in python? That aside, have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Use double quotes to prevent word splitting in your shell script: `python path/test.py "$year"`

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What is it that isn't working exactly?

Comment: If you want to pass a _list_, each list element should be a separate argument. So you'd want `sys.argv[1:]`, not `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: BTW, using `#!/bin/bash` to start a script that's then run with `sh scriptname` is contradictory. `#!/bin/bash` says that the correct interpreter for the script is **bash**. `sh` is not bash -- even when `sh` is a symlink to bash, starting it under that name disables some features for closer compliance with the POSIX sh standard. So either use `#!/bin/sh`, or use `bash yourscript` instead of `sh yourscript`.

Comment: @msanford Yes. it's bc I want to call multiple python scripts with one command. Each script takes the output of previous script as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your shell script, pass the whole argument list through by using `"$@"` to expand to `"$1" "$2" "$3"` ...etc, for however many arguments are available:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Requesting work on years:"
printf ' - %s\n' "$@"
python path/test.py "$@"
```

In your Python script, process that whole argument list:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    print("Working on year", i)
```

Comment: That worked when run `bash test.sh '2021' '2022'`.Do you also know how to make it work if it's an R script instead of `.py` ? Tried `Rscript path/test.R "$@"`, it seems not working.

Comment: You'd need to ask a question that includes the R script.

Comment: @tuangou, ...notice how in the Python above I had to change `sys.argv[1]` to `sys.argv[1:]`? There may be some equivalent change needed in R.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now both `.r` and `.py` would work with your answer.